# About deriving the Fokker-Plank-Smoluchowski equation of a (homogeneous) S.D.E

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

We recall that given a $d-$dimensional stochastic process defined as a solution of a homogeneous S.D.E $dX_t = b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dB_t$ its corresponding infinitesimal generator ${\cal L}$ is s.t it acts on test functions $f$ to give a function ${\cal L}f(x)$ which is,
${\cal L}f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d b_i(x) \partial_i f + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1,j=1}^d (\sigma \sigma^\top)_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j f$.

Given ${\cal L}$ as above, we define the operator ${\cal L}^*$ s.t for any two bounded measurable $f$ and $h$ we have, $\int  ({\cal L}f)h = \int f ({\cal L}^* h)$.

- Can someone kindly give me reference which explains/gives examples as to how is the differential operator form of this ${\cal L}^*$ derived when $\sigma$ is *not* a constant but has a non-trivial dependence on $X_t$?

---

The operator ${\cal L}^*$ is important because of the Forward Kolmogorov/Fokker-Plank-Smoluchowski equation which states that if $\rho_t$ is the density of the stochastic process $X_t$ then it satisfies the P.D.E, $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = {\cal L}^* \rho$. Hence if this P.D.E has to be solved then we necessarily need to find the differential opeartor form of ${\cal L^*}$!

Answer (score 1):

The derivation of the operator $\mathcal{L}^{*}\rho = - \sum_{i=1}^{d}\partial_{i}\left(\rho b_{i}(x)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{d}\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\left((\sigma(x)(\sigma(x))^{\top})_{i,j}\rho\right)$ can be found [in Thm. 2.8 here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Epavl/PavliotisBook.pdf) for the univariate case. The proof is similar in the multivariate case (the result is mentioned in (2.63)-(2.66) in the same ref). See also the hint in [Exercise 8.3 here](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Eywu/research/documents/StochasticDifferentialEquations.pdf) which considers the multivariate case.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see.